# Can you fake a closed question? [‌closed]

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, title

I just had a random thought; what if you append "[closed]" to the end of a question title. Is it filtered out, or in some way disallowed?

If you are seeing this, it isn't. It could potentially be used for some trickery, right? Or maybe not. I don't know, that's why you're here: discuss!

EDIT: Just a recap: Juan Manuel edited and removed "[closed]" from the end of the title and then answered (see below) - but it is technically possible.

Edit 2: Looks like it's still possible, if you play silly tricks with Unicode. (There's a [zero width non-joiner](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/index.phtml?page=02&subpage=0&glyph=0200C) character in the new title.)

Comment: By the way, I'm not exactly sure which of the important tags this belongs to. Feel free to fix!

Comment: I think while possible, it's probably one of those things that falls under the clause "Don't do it. You know better than that."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now explicitly disallowed as of December 2010.

[Reject user-entered titles with the string "[ closed ]" at the end](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70729/reject-user-entered-titles-that-end-with-the-string-closed/72654#72654)

Answer (score 15):

It's quickly edited out by responsible members of the community.

Comment: As are grammatical mistakes :)

Comment: Actually, the mistake was someplace else, fixed

Comment: We have responsible members of the community?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not exactly sure why you'd even do that in the first place. All in all, **faking a closed question can actually be far worse that actually having it closed**. Fewer people will pay attention to it and the ones that do will see the deceit quite quickly and will really close it; it will also probably piss them off, which is not something you really want to do.

Comment: yeah the ROI for this "hack" is basically nil

Comment: See @gnostradamus' answer on why you'd want to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I guess if you're afraid your question will get closed, you could throw "[closed]" on the end of the title in the hopes that anyone who *would* close it when seeing it in the question list *wouldn't* click through to read it (thus seeing it isn't really closed).

I'm guessing that many people still read closed questions anyway, and will thus discover the ruse. I, for example, still clicked through and answered yours. ;)

Comment: I look through heavily downvoted questions that aren't closed :)

Comment: Why would you not want your question to be closed?  Closure just prevents addition of new answers, so it stands to reason you're just trying to get more answers.  But the very tactic that's keeping the question open will also drive away answerers.  So... it's a pointless exercise.

Comment: @Popular: True, but it will attract *reopeners*, who seem to be outnumbering the closers these days.

Comment: But since it's not closed, they don't have anything to reopen, which might flip their "must reopen" bit and cause them to close it...  Then it would be "[closed][closed]"...

Comment: Causing complications such as an infinite loop.